# Accessing Xamarin macOS methods in MAUI

Tags: ios, windows, macos, maui, finder

I'm building a **desktop-only** `MAUI` application where I need to open the `Explorer` (or `Finder` on `MacOS`) on a particular folder at the end of a `Task`.

On `Windows` I can just use the `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync` method, which comes directly from `UWP`.
On `MacCatalyst` however, I've been trying to replicate the `selectFile` method from `NSWorkspace` inside `AppKit` ([link here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1524399-selectfile)) to a `MAUI` project, but without luck.

I've found the [Xamarin Mac SDK interface of the method here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nsworkspace.selectfile?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14):

```
[Foundation.Export("selectFile:inFileViewerRootedAtPath:")]
[ObjCRuntime.ThreadSafe]
public virtual bool SelectFile (string fullPath, string rootFullPath);
```

Supposedly I should be to replicate this in MAUI but I can't find the same class and method, partly due to a lack of documentation on this new framework.

Anyone here got any clues how to do it?

Comment: "MacCatalyst" is an Apple API. It is iOS API plus SOME Mac extensions. Maui simply makes that Apple API available. What you need to find out, is whether Apple's MacCatalyst contains that function or its equivalent. (Or wait until the Maui template offers a "MacOS" option, as an alternative to the current "MacCatalyst".) I haven't targetted Mac (nor MacCatalyst), so that is the extent of my knowledge about this.

Comment: Alright, I think I'll have to wait for a macOS full implementation, because as you implied, MacCatalyst doesn't support the NSWorkspace class. If, by any chance, there's a method to implement the platform's native code, I might try [this solution, which involves using a plugin](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667569)

Comment: *"If, by any chance, there's a method to implement the platform's native code"* My understanding is that currently "MacCatalyst" is as "native" as it gets for mac. Given that `Xamarin.mac` exists, I presume that there will eventually be direct support in Maui for full MacOS. I don't expect to see that until sometime in 2023. (I'm not "in the loop" with devs; that's just my prediction.)